# How do I effectively remove dog hair from my car seat?

Tags: cleaning, car

I am looking for a hack to help me remove stubborn dog hair from my cloth car seat.  It seems resistant to vacuuming.

Comment: Seems like a job for a lint roller, but I haven't tried this.

Answer (score 7):

Wrap duct tape around your hand, sticky side out. Pat the affected area till the tape is full of crud. Repeat until it doesn't pick anything else up. If there is still hair, try putting your hand down a little harder and picking it up with a rolling motion.

Comment: OR... just just cloth roller...

Answer (score 6):

I like magic lint brushes. They remove lint and pet hair very well. I have several laying around the house and in the car.

[http://www.amazon.com/Evercare-Lint-Brush-Magik-Pack/dp/B0097PSU6A/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1423973510&sr=8-2&keywords=lint+brush](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0097PSU6A)

http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=lint+brush

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is a trick I read on another site.  Use a pumice stone or pumice cleaning stone.  I have a Great Dane (big dog with short hair) who leaves an abundance of hair on the cloth seats in my car.  I have tried many methods that have not worked very well until I tried the pumice stone.  Amazing results.

Answer (score 1):

Soak the palm of your hand. Wipe the pet hair off in a downward motion. The hair will ball up and stick to your damp hand. This works because the hair becomes wet, therefore heavier. This results in it being unable to stick to your pants (or whatever surface you're dealing with) in response to static electricityBarely dampen a clean, regular kitchen sponge. Use a sponge mop if you're removing pet hair from a low-pile carpet, in which case the floor should be thoroughly vacuumed first. Rub the fabric, upholstery, or carpet with the sponge. The fur should roll up into clumps that you can pick off by hand.

or
Put on a latex glove. Rub the surface with it on. The pet hair should stick to your glove. This also works with rubber gloves or cloth gardening gloves with a rubber coating on the palm. A rubber bristle push broom can work in the same way on floors. Dampen the glove or rubber section of the glove for increased effectiveness.

or

Inflate a balloon. Rub it across the surface that has pet hair on it. The static on the balloon's surface will attract the hair (and works on yours, too!), which you can collect and then re-use the balloon to get more hair.